# jQuery Knob display

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-knob

I'm using this jQuery knob.

```
http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/
```

I'm using semi circle & i need to show min. & max limits below the knob. By default it doesn't show limits.
Also is it possible to show current knob value (shown at middle of knob) to be shown on dial surface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read documentation from github ?

```
<script>
$('.dial')
    .trigger(
        'configure',
        {
        "min":10,
        "max":40,
        "fgColor":"#FF0000",
        "skin":"tron",
        "cursor":true
        }
    );
</script>
```

[github](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob)

Comment: this does not answers that part of the question: "i need to show min. & max limits below the knob"